# How can I get a title with Escape Characters in from Google feed

Tags: json, google-feed-api

Example: A title with HTML from blog to get:

```
Welcome To <b>Italy Restaurant</b> <p>The best gourmet restaurant available in Italia</p>
```

I use `entry.title.$t` but it returns only text, not Unicode like what I want.

I want it should be:

`Welcome To \u003Cb\u003EItalian Restaurant\u003C\/b\u003E \u003Cp\u003EThe best gourmet restaurant available in Italia \u003C\/p\u003E`

Thanks.

Comment: `\u003C` is the same as `<`, and no one in their right mind would ever encode `<` as `\u003C`,  as it would be completely useless. Why would you want to receive that? Maybe you want the receive `&x3C;` (or `&lt;`), but that doesn't make much sense either in this context.

Comment: Because I want keep HTML format. "HTML Entities" is ok but how can I get it?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep HTML format"? Do you want to see `<b>` literally, or do you want to see bold text? To replace some characters by HTML entities, just use the appropriate function in the language/environment you're using.